# Monitoring deployer service not working in SDL Tridion Sites 9

Tags: content-delivery, deployer, sites-9, monitoring, deployerservice

I'm trying to setup monitoring in SDL Tridion Sites 9. This works fine, except for the deployer service.  This one is throwing the following error:

> 2019-06-06 15:37:56,018 INFO  [com.tridion.monitor.EventDispatcher]
>   ServiceStatusStore - TMA-AG-99999 Status of service 'DeployerService'
>   changed to Error

I have tried to test the url defined in the cd_monitoring_conf.xml to test the deployer service:

http://z1.microservices.staging.intranet.xxxxx.nl:8184/mappings

When testing this in Postmen (because of OAuth enabled) I get the following error:

> Verb POST is not allowed

I have tried it both with the **implementer** and **cmuser**

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

I also had issues with /mapping endpoint for monitoring. It was not stable, even though service was running and /mapping endpoint was accesible via Postman monitoring service returned either not responding or error status. At the end I have reconfigured monitoring service to use /health endpoint (by default in Sites 9 /health is excluded from OAuth in all microservices).